# Change URL without reload Ajax

Tags: ajax

Can I change pages with Ajax + Wordpress without reloading?

Only articles related to dynamic post display or AJAX pagination are available on the web.

Where can I find out about the use of AJAX in 'wp_nav_menu "

Here is my inspiration: (see their navigatio) [LINK](https://www.monolith.pl/)

Comment: You can use js [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) for that

Comment: @Buttered_Toast  Will it help to create something like this? [link](https://www.monolith.pl) - see their navigation - changes the link without reloading

Comment: You want the site content to change as well? without reloading the page? am I correct?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Yes Sir

Comment: Wordpress alone doesn't have the tools to do that, you will need to use angular or react to achieve that. You can use ajax to update sections of your site not whole pages is a big mess with ajax alone, you need to update css and js and update a whole lot. WordPress is not built for that.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast  Hmm, but I can see their site is made on Wordpress. You think they also used Angular or React there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128532/discussion-between-simon-and-buttered-toast).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you linked to isn't updating the nav menu with AJAX, rather, when you click a link they load the target via JS then swap the entire page for the new page.

A little bit of trickery with pushState ensures the URL in the address bar changes and back/forward is preserved. Take a look at the term ***PJAX***, there are JS libraries that implement it, and it may be a more useful search term.

Otherwise your options are limited. If you're building a SPA, you will want to construct your menu and use browser history/current URL to figure out which element to style